# Why doesn't Autofixture Likeness behave like I'd expect for one of these two tests?

Tags: autofixture, semantic-comparison

Given these classes:

```cs
public class DrumAndBassBand
{
    public Drums Drum { get; set; }
    public Bass Bass { get; set; }
}

public class Instrument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Drums : Instrument { }
public class Bass : Instrument { }
```

Why does this test pass...

```cs
[Fact]
public void DrumAndBassBand_Equality_Behaves_As_Expected_Version_One()
{
    // arrange
    var template = new Fixture().Create<DrumAndBassBand>();

    // act
    var createdBand = new DrumAndBassBand {Drum = template.Drum, Bass = template.Bass};

    // assert         
    var createdLikeness = createdBand.AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
        .Without(x => x.Bass)
        .CreateProxy();
    createdLikeness.Drum = createdBand.Drum;

    Assert.True(createdLikeness.Equals(template));

    var templateLikeness = template.AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
        .Without(x => x.Bass)
        .CreateProxy();
    templateLikeness.Drum = template.Drum;

    Assert.True(templateLikeness.Equals(createdBand));
}
```

...and this one fail? (the difference is the `DrumAndBaseBand` instantiation)

```cs
[Fact]
public void DrumAndBassBand_Equality_Behaves_As_Expected_Version_Two()
{
    // arrange
    var template = new Fixture().Create<DrumAndBassBand>();

    // act
    var createdBand =
        new DrumAndBassBand
        {
            Drum = new Drums { Name = template.Drum.Name, SerialNumber = template.Drum.SerialNumber },
            Bass = new Bass { Name = template.Bass.Name, SerialNumber = template.Bass.SerialNumber }
        };

    // assert
    var createdLikeness = createdBand.AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
        .Without(x => x.Bass)
        .CreateProxy();
    createdLikeness.Drum = createdBand.Drum;

    Assert.True(createdLikeness.Equals(template));

    var templateLikeness = template.AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
        .Without(x => x.Bass)
        .CreateProxy();
    templateLikeness.Drum = template.Drum;

    Assert.True(templateLikeness.Equals(createdBand));
}
```

Comment: From version 3.0.4 and above the values are automatically copied to the proxy instance (which means, `createdLikeness.Drum = createdBand.Drum;` is going to happen automatically).

Comment: Well done, sir. Well done, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second test, the `Drum` and `Bass` instances are different from the *template* where you are trying to compare.

You can always run a `Likeness` (without creating a Proxy) and inspect the output:

```
Test 'DrumAndBassBand_Equality_Behaves_As_Expected_Version_Two' failed: 

Ploeh.SemanticComparison.LikenessException:
    The provided value DrumAndBassBand did not match the expected value DrumAndBassBand. 

The following members did not match: 
- Drum.
```

That basically means that you have to provide a hint when creating a `Likeness` for the the comparison of the `Drum` instance.

The first half of the test becomes:

```
var createdLikeness = createdBand
    .AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
    .With(x => x.Drum)
        .EqualsWhen((s, d) => s.Drum == createdBand.Drum)
    .Without(x => x.Bass)
    .CreateProxy();
```

The source destination's `Drums` equals *other* `Drums` when it is really a *createdBand* instance `Drum`.

Similarly, the second half of the test becomes:

```
var templateLikeness = template
    .AsSource().OfLikeness<DrumAndBassBand>()
    .With(x => x.Drum)
        .EqualsWhen((s, d) => s.Drum == template.Drum)
    .Without(x => x.Bass)
    .CreateProxy();
```

The above allow you to have *very flexible* comparisons (and you can always customize it even further).

Comment: Thanks, Nikos - that did the trick.  I hadn't seen anything good on the use of With().EqualsWhen() so far, so this is great!